# Node.js two versions installation

Tags: shell, node.js, version, npm

I created a SHELL service from [Shellmix](http://shellmix.com).

Node.js v5.8-pre was installed in the hosting machine under directory `/usr/local/bin/`. However I would like to install v6.6 under my `$HOME` directory.

I have successfully installed node.js v6.6 in my `$HOME` directory with

```
> ./configure --prefix=$HOME/
> gmake
> gmake install
> alias node $HOME/bin/node
> alias npm $HOME/bin/npm
> alias node-waf $HOME/bin/node-waf
```

When I try `node app.js`, it really using v6.6 node.js. However when I try `npm`, it gave me an error.

```
Error: npm doesn't work with node v0.5.8-pre
Required: node@0.6 || 0.7 || 0.8
    at /homex/hkalex/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:60:23
    at Object.<anonymous> (/homex/hkalex/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:80:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:470:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:200:26)
```

Sorry that I am not good at Linux environment. Could any one help me to make npm work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did fix this problem.

I modified the first line of `npm-cli.js` from

`#!/usr/bin/env node`

to

`#!/usr/bin/env /homex/hkalex/bin/node`

Comment: Why not simply `#!/homex/hkalex/bin/node`?

Answer (score 2):

You should really just use [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to make your life a lot easier.